# Storing data needed to be retrieved in my mobile app

Tags: android, database, server, cloud

I have seen many examples retrieving data from websites to be used as contents of applications. Now I am developing my own app, I have my own contents to be delivered to my users, where am I supposed to store my contents so it can be retrieved from my app? Is it a server? Or a cloud? I have done some research on Parse, AWS, Google Cloud Platform, they all seem pretty confusing to me. Is it correct that this is the right approach of storing app content?

Please help and give me some advice. I have no experience in these, sorry...

Comment: It would be useful if you could clarify which kind of app you're thinking about, Regarding this sort of data you want the users to retrieve, the storaging method may vary :)

Comment: I am developing an app that allow users to download images I designed from my app. There is no user uploading or user data backup functionality. So I am confused about which kind of server or cloud service I should use to store these images to be retrieved by my user? Which is the best solution for my situation? @Jorge33212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rule of thumb as someone who only knows Google and Amazon AWS.

If the data is images / movies / files: use AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage

If the data is text, use database system:

- For RDBMS like MySQL use AWS RDS or Google Cloud SQL
- For NoSql: AWS SimpleDb, DynamoDb. In Google Cloud hosting MongoDb is its [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mongodb/).

You don't need a special service to host a database but we're paying for performance.

All file's metadata (like url, name, etc) should be stored in database. Then create a server to serve the so-called REST API in the cloud that acts like the brain to connect all the dots, manage data operation and as much pre-processing as possible so your user devices won't get burdened. You can create a starter cloud instance for cheap in AWS EC2 or Google Cloud Engine.

**Case example: tracking user downloads**

This is very simple. The key is *not* to give the image url right away but wrap it in a request. Let's say the image is photo.jpg and the user who downloads or requests it is Bob (normally we get user information through a login in the app and we are mostly interested not in name but email or social media credentials). So you can create a server that processes a request through http://www.example.com/track?name=bob&image=photo

By processing, your server takes all the parameters "Bob", "photo", and probably also time and location if needed then save these values in your database. Then you return the real url of photo.jpg as response to Bob's request. There you go, you have Bob tracked.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and info! I am developing an app that allow users to download images I designed from my app. There is no user uploading or user data backup functionality. I would also like to track down the downloads of each image(Not sure how it can be achieved?x,D). So I am confused about which kind of server or cloud service I should use to store these images to be retrieved by my user? Which is the cost effective best solution for my situation? @inmyth

Comment: Does data in AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage can handle a lot of requests by users? @inmyth

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example to track user download. For pricing, it clearly depends on your needs. Both AWS and Google have calculator which you can play around with. If you are starter with a a few data and few downloads, it's unlikely you're going to pay a couple dollars in a month. As whether they can handle a lot of requests ... these companies handle clients like New York Times and Dropbox. They sure can serve needs of a mortal.

Comment: I forgot to say. If you're new to AWS you get free basic use for a year. In Google you only get store credit which gets burned in a few months

Comment: So to store and retrieve images i will only need AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage? There is no need to involve EC2 or google app engine stuff? @inmyth

Comment: Yes. You can even use Google Drive to host your images. Just set the permission as public. I forgot how much free quota they give. Maybe 2GB.

Comment: Can google drive handle multiple requests from clients app at the same time? @inmyth

Comment: They all can handle multiple requests. S3 et al make money not only by selling storage but also data transfer. The more the file gets downloaded (which counts toward total data transfer) the more you pay. What I don't know is if Google Drive being a freebie has hidden limits that cap total number or size of downloads. So to be safe, just use S3 or something similar.